# injection order

Tags: spring-mvc

How do I get instance of Log4j initialized after reading from config file and injecting property

My code is:

```
private static String LogPath;

@Value("#{settings['LogDirPath']}")
private static void setLogDirPath(String LogDirPath)
{
        LogPath = LogDirPath;
}

private static final Logger fileLogger = LoggerSetup.GetLogger(<Class Name>, <Logger Name>, LogPath);
```

However when I step into GetLogger, the logpath is always null.

How do I ensure that fileLogger is called after the config file injection is done?

UPDATE1:

```
@Value("#{settings['LogDirPath']}")
private  String LogPath;

private static Logger googleLogger = LoggerSetup.GetLogger(<Class Name>, <Logger Name>, LogPath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the fileLogger variable (which thus can't be final) in the `setLogDirPath()` method. A class field is initialized at class loading time, before any methof of the class can be called.

That said, I'm pretty sure you can't use this annotation on a static method. Spring injects fields, constructors or instance setter methods.

Comment: Would it be better to have it as shown in 'UPDATE1' in my op? What does 'final' give me?

Comment: That wouldn't even compile. You're referring to an instance field from a static initializer. ALso, respect the Java naming conventions: variables start with a lower-case letter. Your logger should not be static.

Comment: I am not working with my code and would be PIA to refactor to correct naming convention/style.

Comment: I made changes as you suggested. In my controller-> default method that gets called, i put in logger.info("Hello"). I noticed the file got created, however it writes out 2 statements with same log message.

Comment: Issues is with multiple loggers in same class. http://www.slf4j.org/nlog4j/TROUBLESHOOT.html#duplicates